# controller member

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In my mvc application, i'm having a controller where many actions are their.

I'm having a property for the controller class.

In index controller i'm setting the value for the property ,

will it able to get same value in another action..

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
    {
int sample =0;

public ActionResult Index(int query)
        {
        this.sample = test;
        }

        public ActionResult Result()
        {
        this.sample  -------- can this 'll give the value of wat i get in index action.

    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Since the controller will be created and destroyed with each web request, you can't store data in private variables across web requests, which is a good thing because, different users will be making different requests, so you need to use caching.

Try this:

```
  public class HomeController : BaseController
  {

      public ActionResult Index(int query)
      {
          ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["query"] = query;
      }

      public ActionResult Result()
      {
          int query = (int)ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["query"];
      }
  }
```

Comment: i have used tempdata will it be common to all user or for single connection seperate tempdata will be there..?

Comment: The TempData Data Dictionary is available for the current request and the immediately next request for a single user.

Comment: instead of using cache you can store it in HttpContext.session["query"], is this a better option ? .. thanks

Comment: Yes, Session is just a user-specific cache, so no need to reinvent it.

Comment: I got turned off to Session a while back, but I have no rational reason for being so. Thanks for reminding me, I edited the answer.